# strategies to help you score or your score?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Strategies to help **you** score high ?
>
> Strategies to help **your** score high ?

Which one is true ? Why ? Can you explain with examples and also what grammar is this about?

Answer (score 0):

You mean "Which one is *correct*?"

In the first one, *score* is a verb - 'to help you to score high'.

In the second, it's a noun - 'to help your score to be high' or, better, 'to help you to get a high score'.

Comment: The second sentence is not idiomatic.  Maybe, *Strategies to help **lift** your score **higher.***

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - Yes, I know - my suggestions were meant to be alternatives.

Comment: An alternative might be: "Strategies to help your high score."

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is correct. The second is bad grammar.

The structure of "help" is: *[ "help" + noun + base verb ]*

"Score" can be a noun or a verb.

In the first sentence, "you" is the noun, and "score" is the base verb. "High" is an adverb that modifies "score".

In the second sentence, "your score" is the noun, and there is no verb because "high" isn't a verb. "Your" cannot be the noun because it's a *possessive adjective*, not a pronoun.